# How to handle two players playing on one keyboard with Box2D (LibGDX)?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, multiplayer, keyboard

I'm making a racing game with LibGDX and Box2D. I've been using this [tutorial](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/top-down-car) to implement the basic physics, and it works properly.

My **main problem** is to implement two different sets of keys (*UP-DOWN-LEFT-RIGHT* and *ASDW*) to control two different instances of a Car class on a same screen.

The code I have yet for handling one set of input (for KeyDown):

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.UP) {
        if (!pressedKeys.contains(Key.Up)) {
            pressedKeys.add(Key.Up);
        }
    } else if (keycode == Input.Keys.DOWN) {
        if (!pressedKeys.contains(Key.Down)) {
            pressedKeys.add(Key.Down);
        }
    } else if (keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT) {
        if (!pressedKeys.contains(Key.Left)) {
            pressedKeys.add(Key.Left);
        }
    } else if (keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT) {
        if (!pressedKeys.contains(Key.Right)) {
            pressedKeys.add(Key.Right);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

(KeyUp):

```
    @Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.UP) {
        if (pressedKeys.contains(Key.Up)) {
            pressedKeys.remove(Key.Up);
        }
    } else if (keycode == Input.Keys.DOWN) {
        if (pressedKeys.contains(Key.Down)) {
            pressedKeys.remove(Key.Down);
        }
    } else if (keycode == Input.Keys.LEFT) {
        if (pressedKeys.contains(Key.Left)) {
            pressedKeys.remove(Key.Left);
        }
    } else if (keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT) {
        if (pressedKeys.contains(Key.Right)) {
            pressedKeys.remove(Key.Right);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

How should I do to be able to handle *UP-DOWN-LEFT-RIGHT* and *ASDW* keys simultaneously?

Note: A Car is instantiated in the main class.

**I can always add more code if needed.**

Comment: I really don't understand where the problem is. Can you please elaborate where you have problems to route key input events to the correct entity?

Comment: Are both players controlling the same car?

Comment: each player is controlling ONE car

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to accomplish with your pressed keys object, but here's a suggestion.

Create a car controller class which takes a car as a parameter in its constructor. And has several action objects that you can bind to. Here's an example for the accelerator (I haven't compiled this so it may need some tweaking)

```
public class CarController{
    public ICallable<Void> pushAccelerator;
    public ICallable<Void> releaseAccelerator;
    public CarController(final Car car)
    {
       pushAccelerator = new ICallable<Void>(){
           public Void call(){
               car.pushAccelerator();
               return null;
           }
       }
       releaseAccelerator = new ICallable<Void>(){
           public Void call(){
               car.releaseAccelerator();
               return null;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Then in your input handler you could have two mappings, one when the key is pressed, one when the key is released.

```
private Map<Integer,ICallable<Void>> keyPressedHandlers = new HashMap<Integer,ICallable<Void>>();
private Map<Integer,ICallable<Void>> keyUpHandlers = new HashMap<Integer,ICallable<Void>>();

public void mapInputs(Car car1, Car car2){
   CarController controller1 = new CarController(car1);
   CarController controller2 = new CarController(car2);
   keyPressedHandlers.put(Keys.W,controller1.pushAccelerator);
   keyPressedHandlers.put(Keys.UP,controller2.pushAccelerator);
   keyUpHandlers.put(Keys.W,controller1.releaseAccelerator);
   keyUpHandlers.put(Keys.UP,controller2.releaseAccelerator);
}

public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if(keyPressedHandlers.containsKey(keycode)){
        keyPressedHandlers.get(keycode).call();
    }
 }

 public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    if(keyUpHandlers.containsKey(keycode)){
        keyUpHandlers.get(keycode).call();
    }
 }
```

This sort of mapping approach even makes it so you could eventually allow a user to map their own keys to the car's actions.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Basically, I just want to implement 2 players mode for my racing game, and make the game listen to multiple keys simultaneously :) I don't know if that was more clear...